# How to completely remove references in a project?

Tags: ios, reference, xamarin

I removed the references on the path, but the link still exists. 
Xamarin is giving the following error:

Native linking error: warning: directory not found for option ../somefolder/somelibrary' (MT5309)

Is there a file where I can delete this link?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I added the library again as a reference and deleted it in the proper way:
-In the solution explorer go to the project
-Go to the (native) Reference folder
-Gear button behind the reference
-Select the option Delete